# send email using sendmail

Tags: backup, email, mail, scripts, sendmail

I'm using a script that sends mail using mail utils but now I want to send mail using sendmail can anyone help me as I was not able to get the same result from sendmail as I did from mail.

```
#Email Settings
Message_Success="Application Backup generated successfully"
Message_Failure="Problem occured while generating Application Backup please verify"

Subject="Application Backup Status Mail"

Recipients="tarun@gmail.com"

#Check if Backup is complete
if [ -e "$Backup_File" ]; then
echo "Today's Backup File Exist's" >> $Log_File
echo "$Message_Success" | mail -s "$Subject" "$Recipients"
else
echo "Today's Backup File Not Found" >> $Log_File
echo "$Message_Failure" | mail -s "$Subject" "$Recipients"
fi
```

I figured out a bit of it and here it is. But where can I define the emails subject.

```
echo "$Message_Success" | sendmail -f sender@email.com "$Recipients"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write

```
if [ -e "$Backup_File" ]; then
    echo "Today's Backup File Exist's" >> $Log_File
else
    echo "Today's Backup File Not Found" >> $Log_File
fi
{
    printf "To: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n" "$Recipients" "$Subject"
    if [ -e "$Backup_File" ]; then
        echo "$Message_Success"
    else
        echo "$Message_Failure"
    fi
} | /path/to/sendmail -oi -t -f sender@example.com
```

You're writing the message with headers, and passing to sendmail. The `-t` flag forces sendmail to read the recipients from the messasge.

Comment: You need to separate the header from the body with an additional blank line. That's why I have 2 `\n` at the end of my printf format string.